# Python conflict Numpy vs Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have no idea whats going on with Python 3.6.2(Anaconda), I tried all day to install numpy and scipy! I have 3 error message: (it depend what package I install first, or change the order of install)

1. ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
2. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
3. NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined

Versions that I used: 
Windows 10,
Anaconda (Python 3.6.2),
Numpy 1.13.3,
Scipy 0.19.1

I tried everything, delete all environment vars. Install new Anaconda(Python 3.6.2)
Download numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl, and opencv_python-3.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl, install it through pip install, change the order of install. Used `conda install scipy` And nothing work!

Maybe its versions conflicts ?

Does anybody know, what is the steps to install and use cv2, numpy, scipy?

Comment: I thought Anaconda came with numpy included with mkl, why are you manually installing after that?

Comment: Yes, for sure but after youre install cv2 or scipy - its going to error - NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined

Comment: No, not really. If it does, you broke something (the only thing which can happen is conda complaining about incompatible versions of cv2 and numpy for example; before installing!).

Comment: Ok, pls tell me the steps! I really dont know what to do !

Comment: Remove everything. Read anacondas docs and re-install anaconda. Now everything is there except opencv. Then again: read the docs, e.g. about conda-forge opencv or alternative repos.

Comment: You install Anaconda then have a cup of tea. It sorts this for you.

Comment: Don't download the wheels for numpy/scipy base libraries, Anaconda sorts that. If it's openCV causing the issue, see :https://www.scivision.co/install-opencv-python-windows/ or tackle that problem specifically.

Comment: Just right now, I installed Anaconda(3.6), used (conda install -c conda-forge opencv) and have an error - name 'numpy' is not defined, in my package I have numpy 1.13.3

Comment: I think its a bug, or version conflict !

Comment: "in my package I have numpy 1.13.3" this is a bit vague. please do list explicitly *all* the steps you have taken to install the software. Including a copy-paste of the terminal commands for all the parts that were done in the terminal. Then, copy-paste with "quote" or "code" formatting the full error log.

Comment: My steps:
1. Install Anaconda last ver(3.6.2)
2. conda install -c conda-forge opencv
3. Get error "name 'numpy' is not defined"
4. Check my package (numpy is installed)